# Microsoft Bot Framework authentication does not support concurrent logged in user?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a bot that was deployed in Azure and it was connected to Microsoft Team. However, there's a problem with authentication. I don't know what to call it so I'll be explaining it.

The bot was responsible for answering a series of questions. The user who chats to the bot will be asked to log in. We used the default log in mechanism from the bot documentation. Single user login is fine but when a second user from a different conversation or even different computer login as well, it will overwrite the token of the first user. The state of the conversation is not affected. In this pattern, if the third user login, the token will be overwritten again.

Why is the token result always the same?

Comment: Can you share your code? Regarding "default login mechanism", please point to this documentation to help us better understand. Perhaps this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: @DanaV Hi, thank you for answering my question. We are using the [JS version of the bot authentication] (https://aka.ms/v4js-bot-auth-sample). We followed strictly with the code sample from the document. However, we did save the token for usage that is not related to the authentication flow. At least that's what we thought.

Comment: Here's the snippet of us saving the token: 
```
async loginResult(step) {
    let tokenResp = step.result;
    if (tokenResp != null) {
       await step.context.sendActivity("You are now logged in.");
       token = tokenResp.token;
       return await step.endDialog();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the newer Teams auth sample found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/46.teams-auth). Teams works a little differently, and needs a slightly different approach.